# Microsoft Family: why can't I unlimit Google Chrome (it's not even on the list) time limit?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Why can't I **unlimit** Google Chrome (it's not even on the list) time limit via Microsoft Family? Every time my child tries to run Google Chrome, there's a warning about time limit and my child has to "ask for time extension", and I have to "allow" this from my Microsoft Family account. My child's laptop is a very recent one, running Windows 10.

I'm trying to get rid of this annoying behaviour and I've **removed** the screen and "app" **limits** for my child's laptop but it doesn't have any effect at all for Google Chrome!

[image]

Moreover, when I view the Apps whose limits are manageable by Microsoft Family, Google Chrome isn't even on that list. There's Chromium, but no Chrome. I find it very weird:

[image]

Is there any other setting I should check on my Microsoft Family account, or on my child's Windows 10 laptop?

Funny thing is, my child can use Edge browser to browse Internet freely so for all practical purposes, there's no time limit for web browsing, but we're used to Chrome, and we really want to get rid of this annoying time warning every single day. To make it more annoying, I can only give a time extension of 3 hours and not more than that.

There must be a way to indicate that no limits should apply to Chrome's running time on that laptop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can try to sign-out and sign-in again? Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to look at elsewhere on that page: "**Content Restrictions**" which is not visible on https://account.microsoft.com/family/ (horrible UX and huge disappointment!)

I had to:

- click on Activity on the ... main menu (if I can call it that),
- see on that page the "**Apps and games**" group, and a "Change restrictions" link associated with that, click on that,
- click on "Show all" for the "**Always blocked**" group, and then finally find "Chrome", and click on the "Remove".

Now on my child laptop, whenever he runs Chrome, no more "you should ask for more time" warnings. The problem is finally solved for me. Good luck to other parents who have to deal with Microsoft Family connected devices and various applications running on them.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much i was losing my mind... almost 2 years on from your answer and they still haven't fixed this issue or made it more accessible.. thanks again!

Sam

P.S Menu has slightly changed for parents looking for this option,
log into https://family.microsoft.com
then click on your childs profile,
then click Content Filters,
then click Apps and Games and
there you should see Blocked Apps and you can click Chrome Browser and Click Remove.